# How do I view ServiceFabric *.dtr files

Tags: logging, azure-service-fabric

Are these blobs fronted by something else?
I can download and unzip them but how do I view them, should I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are used by the SF product team when providing support for issues.  We have a client tool that makes viewing them easy. They require a great deal of internal knowledge to make sense of so we haven't talked about them publicly.